# syntax error, unexpected T_PRINT, expecting T_STRING

Tags: php

i'm getting this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_PRINT, expecting T_STRING in 
/homepages/26/d94605010/htdocs/lz/writecodeonline.com/php/index.php(190) 
: eval()'d code on line 7
```

Example:

```
   Class HelloWorld
    {   
      public $word;

      public function print()  
      {    
        echo $this->"hi";    
      }    
    }

    $word = new HelloWorld();
    $word = print();
```

Comment: This is a good example for what **not** to do in OOP :D

Comment: This code contains many errors... I really recommend to reread http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`print()` is a reserved keyword. Also, this is invalid code:

```
        echo $this->"hi";
```

You will get this error:

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'
```

You should do it as:

```
Class HelloWorld
{   
  public $word = 'hi';

  public function printWord()  
  {    
    echo $this->word;    
  }    
}

$word = new HelloWorld();
$word = $word->printWord();
```

Answer (score 4):

`print` is a reserved word in PHP.

You need to give your method some other name.

Comment: still getting error after renaming method to abc() Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' in /homepages/26/d94605010/htdocs/lz/writecodeonline.com/php/index.php(190) : eval()'d code on line 11

Answer (score 0):

replace `echo $this->"hi";` with `echo "hi";`, call `$word->function();` instead of `$word = function();` and rename `print` to something else